# adding has_many association in a model through a plugin - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails project where project model has many issues.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :issues
end
```

Now through a plugin i want to add an association in the project model, say has_many :activities

so that project model will look like

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :issues
    has_many :activities
end
```

where activity is a model of my plugin.

Can this be done using hooks? Please give some example.

Comment: How did you do at the end? I need the same thing, but I cannot make out where to put the file and how to name it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a whirl:

```
module ProjectExt
  def self.included base
    base.has_many :activities
  end
end

require 'project'    
Project.send(:include, ProjectExt)
```

Comment: did u mean base.has_many :activities? because issues are already associated. also where should i put this module?

Comment: Sure--the goal here is to show you ruby syntax for extending a class with Rails' association class methods.

Comment: How do you name this file and where do you place it?

Answer (score 2):

You can add it by

```
Project.has_many :activities
```

You can do that in your plugin after getting the class where you association is.

Comment: so i need to include the above line in my activity model?

Comment: can you provide some more hints, because i am getting undefined method `activities' for #<Project:0xb4ca47d4>

Comment: You need doing on Class not on an Object.